# how to set tool tip for the aspxtextboxes to show their text contents?

Tags: textbox, devexpress, asp.net

i have been working with devexpress  AspxTextbox, in asp.net and c#.net?

initially i was struggling to settext for aspx text boxes,but after that i got a tip that clientinstancename.settext() with custom js properties solve that issue.

now the problem is i have to set the tool tip for the aspxtextboxes to show their text contents ? how could that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <ClientSideEvents EndCallback="function(s,e)
{                                      clientCADIncidentNo.mainElement.title=s.cpUnReconcileCADIncidentNo;   
                                    }" />
```

where cpUnReconcileCADIncidentNo is the jsproperties key whichis assigned in the required event as below

```
((ASPxGridView)sender).JSProperties["cpUnReconcileSafetyPADIncidentNo"] ="texttobeshownastooltip";
```